# When we Load data into Hive table from HDFS, it deletes the file from source directory(HDFS)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

When we Load data into Hive table from HDFS, it deletes the file from source directory(HDFS) is there a way we can keep the file in the source directory and load the data into hive table as well.

I used the below query;

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'source_file_path' insert INTO TABLE TABLENAME;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive does not do any transformation while loading data into tables. [Load operations](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables) are currently pure copy/move operations that move datafiles into locations corresponding to Hive tables.

Use `hadoop fs cp` or `hdfs dfs cp` commands to copy (not move) files:

```
hadoop fs -cp [source_file_path] [table_location_path]
```

or

```
hdfs  dfs cp [source_file_path] [table_location_path]
```

Use `decribe formatted tablename` command to check table location path.